# Getting acknowledge error in CAN Loop-back mode

Tags: avr, can-bus

I am using CAN for testing purposes in loop back mode in AT90CAN128 which is similar to other AVR microcontrollers. I am trying to run it in loop back mode, however I get an acknowledge error. In other words, the AERR bit field of the CANSTMOB register is set. How can I fix it? Or at lease, please point out what can be cause of such an error in loop back mode. I am using one single node and the transmiter is expected to send the acknoledgement to the transmiter itself and in loop back mode there should be no problem. This is my code:

```
int main(){
    // reseting everything (Because MOBs are not initialized after reset)
    CANGCON = (1 << SWRES);
    for (uint8_t mob= 0; mob < 14; mob++) {
        CANPAGE = (mob <<  4);
        CANCDMOB = 0;
        CANSTMOB = 0;
    }
    CANBT1 = 0x62;  // Baud Rate set to 20Kbp
    CANBT2 = 0x0C;
    CANBT3 = 0x37;
    
    CANGIE    = 0xFF;
    CANIE2   |=  (1 << IEMOB0) | (1 << IEMOB1);
    
    /// Reception Config
    CANPAGE   = (1 << AINC);
    CANSTMOB  = 0;
    
    CANIDT1   = 0;
    CANIDT2   = 0;
    CANIDT3   = 0;
    CANIDT4   = 0;
    
    CANIDM1   = 0;
    CANIDM2   = 0;
    CANIDM3   = 0;
    CANIDM4   = 0;
    
    CANCDMOB  = (1 << CONMOB1) | (1 << DLC0) | (1 << IDE);  // Reception Enable

    // Prepare MOB for Sending
    CANPAGE   = (1 << MOBNB0) | (1 << AINC);
    CANCDMOB  = 0;
    
    CANIDT1   = 0;
    CANIDT2   = 0;
    CANIDT3   = 0;
    CANIDT4   = 0;
    
    CANIDM1   = 0;
    CANIDM2   = 0;
    CANIDM3   = 0;
    CANIDM4   = 0;
    CANMSG    = 0xAA;

    CANGCON  |= (1 << ENASTB) | (1 << LISTEN);   // Enable CAN in Loopback

    // Sending the preconfigured send MOB
    CANPAGE   = (1 << MOBNB0) | (1 << AINC);
    
    CANCDMOB  = (1 << CONMOB0) | (1 << DLC0) | (1 << IDE);  // Send Enabled

}
```

Comment: Questions asking for code/libraries are explicitly off-topic.